# ArcGIS Intersect using Geometry Service

Tags: intersection, arcgis-silverlight-api

I am using the intersect service from the ArcGIS Geometry service.
referring : [http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/sil....htm#Intersect](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm#Intersect)

I have modified it to make it work with polylines
it works fine to intersect a polyline with a polygon but does not return anything when I try intersecting a polyline with a polyline?

Answer (score 3):

Are both datasets in the same spatial reference?
[Are you including the spatial reference for the polylines?](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Polyline.html)
[The intersection.method returns the envelope or null if they don't intersect.](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Envelope~Intersection.html)

Comment: HI , Thank you for replying, Yes both the dataset are in the same spatial reference, and yes I a including the spatial reference for polyline intersect, I a not using ArcObjects , I am using the geometry service of ArcGIS [link]http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer/intersect .. Please guide

Comment: I think I would need more information to be of help as not returning anything is the expected behavior for no intersection. If you run this from the arcgis interface do you get any return?